# Invalid characters passed for attempted conversion, these have been ignored - Pushing Laravel project to heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I am trying to take a laravel project from a server and move it to heroku following all the provided steps, when pushing the repo to heroku, I encounter the following error :

```
 Compiling common classes
remote:        
remote:
remote:          [ErrorException]
remote:          Invalid characters passed for attempted conversion, these have been ignored
```

I have been looking at a guthub issue that states this error - [[PHP 7.4 RC3] Invalid characters passed for attempted conversion, these have been ignored #2003](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/2003) - Which is one of the few answers I can find.
However the file this issue is referencing does not exist in my project (vendor/dompdf/dompdf/lib/Cpdf.php).

One of the answers suggested turning off error reporting by adding `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);` to the file that throws the error. Any idea of where to put that line?

I can't see what file the error is being thrown on. See message :

```
      Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 1
remote:  !     WARNING: A post-install-cmd script terminated with an error
remote:
remote:  !     ERROR: Dependency installation failed!
```

I may be doing something obvoiusly wrong. Followed these steps for the migration : [Deploy Laravel Projects On Heroku](https://medium.com/laravel-power-devs/deploy-laravel-projects-on-heroku-922776c68243)

EDIT: Also tried `composer update` as suggested in the answer to this question [printing-preview-doesnt-working-laravel-dompdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59772891/printing-preview-doesnt-working-laravel-dompdf)

EDIT 2: Below is the the build log :

```
  Package mtdowling/cron-expression is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use dragonmantank/cron-expression instead.
remote:        Generating optimized autoload files
remote:        Carbon 1 is deprecated, see how to migrate to Carbon 2.
remote:        https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-carbon-2
remote:            You can run './vendor/bin/upgrade-carbon' to get help in updating carbon and other frameworks and libraries that depend on it.
remote:        1 package you are using is looking for funding.
remote:        Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
remote:        > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postInstall
remote:        > php artisan optimize
remote:        Generating optimized class loader
remote:        Compiling common classes
remote:        
remote:
remote:          [ErrorException]
remote:          Invalid characters passed for attempted conversion, these have been ignored
remote:
remote:
remote:        Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 1
remote:  !     WARNING: A post-install-cmd script terminated with an error
remote:
remote:  !     ERROR: Dependency installation failed!
remote:  !
remote:  !     The 'composer install' process failed with an error. The cause
remote:  !     may be the download or installation of packages, or a pre- or
remote:  !     post-install hook (e.g. a 'post-install-cmd' item in 'scripts')
remote:  !     in your 'composer.json'.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Typical error cases are out-of-date or missing parts of code,
remote:  !     timeouts when making external connections, or memory limits.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Check the above error output closely to determine the cause of
remote:  !     the problem, ensure the code you're pushing is functioning
remote:  !     properly, and that all local changes are committed correctly.
remote:  !
remote:  !     For more information on builds for PHP on Heroku, refer to
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support
remote:  !
remote:  !     REMINDER: the following warnings were emitted during the build;
remote:  !     check the details above, as they may be related to this error:
remote:  !     - A post-install-cmd script terminated with an error
```

I've tried updating the `mtdowling/cron-expression` package - but it keeps reverting to it. Could this, or the Carbon error be causing the "Invalid characters error" ?

Comment: Upgrading the dependency in `composer.json` would be the cleanest solution. Installing the dependencies can be done with `composer install` or `php composer.phar install`

Comment: I had the same issue using Docker. I tried to downgrade PHP version, but that didn't solve it.

Comment: @AlaaBadran Eventually after messing around with PHP versions (Mine was very old ) Using Docker and changing the heroku stack to "Heroku-16" via the cli seemed to do the trick - Will try to post an answer soon

Comment: @Paddymac I found some missing php extensions.. I installed them and it worked fine

Answer (score 4):

Upgrading the `dompdf/dompdf` to version `0.8.5` will solve this issue: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases

Installing the latest version can be done with:

```
composer require dompdf/dompdf
```

or modifying `composer.json` manually to `0.8.5` and running:

```
composer install
```

Keep in mind this upgrade may contain breaking changes

Comment: No luck.. Doesn't seem to make any difference. Bare in mind I don't need that actual package. Its just the one that's associated with the error I'm getting.

Answer (score 0):

What fixed this issue the last time it occured was to switch the heroku stack to '**heroku-16**' but with it becoming deprecated next month (May 2021) I tried to upgrade the stack and was faced with the same error again.. This time I found that with the later stack (**heroku-20**) that the two post cmds weren't being run correctly

```
      "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
```

I'm assuming these post install commands work for the older stack or something and that's why I was getting the errors originally.. I removed these two steps from the composer.json and the project built perfect. Then I added the post install commands into a new **app.json** file, in the root directory for heroku to pick up. An example of that file here >

```
{
  "name": "Site name here",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "postdeploy": "php artisan optimize"
  },
  "buildpacks": [
    {
      "url": "https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php"
    }
  ]
}
```

the build pack here is a reference to the newest php stack. After adding this app.json the whole project was deployed successfully.